# Recursive DELETE statement to remove all posts within topic category and all subtopics

Tags: postgresql

I have a challenge I am solving that requires me to do the following:

"Delete all published posts in the “Customer Success” topic and its subtopics. A subtopic is a child or descendant topic (similar to folders vs subfolders) and can include many levels. For example, there might be a topic “Company” with a subtopic “Engineering” with a subtopic “Backend” with a subtopic “Elixir” so the hierarchy is Company > Engineering > Backend > Elixir. Here Elixir is also a subtopic of Company."

The tables I have that may be included in this statement are the: public.topics, public.posts_topics, and public.posts

I am new to PostgreSQL and have never done anything like a recursive deletion of child elements before. I know the posts_topics table has a foreign key to both the posts and topics tables.

Does anyone have any advice for how this statement should be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create an appropriate table structure you should think about FOREIGN KEYS. The FK connects a record in one table with a record of the same or another table. You can tell the FK that the related record must be deleted if the referenced record is deleted. This is done in the table definition using

```
FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES another_table(primary_key_column) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae7379f4dd16400946cd132efacb6df3)

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    -- references another id in same table (build the topic hierarchy)
    parent int REFERENCES topics(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    post_text text,
    -- connects the owner topic to the post
    owner_id int REFERENCES topics(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- in fact, because we are using the owner_id in table "posts",
-- this table is not really required anymore but you requested it
CREATE TABLE posts_topics (
    p_id int REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    t_id int REFERENCES topics(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

---

However, if you really wanted to do this with a recursive query, the query could look like this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e3c51ca1d8f6ac0492abb84d397ae967)

```
WITH RECURSIVE trace_tree AS (
    SELECT id                                            -- 1
    FROM topics
    WHERE id = 2
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t.id                                          
    FROM topics t
    JOIN trace_tree tt ON tt.id = t.parent
), del_posts_topics AS (                                 -- 2                        
    DELETE FROM posts_topics WHERE t_id = ANY (
        SELECT * FROM trace_tree
    )
    RETURNING p_id                                       
), del_posts AS (                                        -- 3
    DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ANY (
        SELECT * FROM del_posts_topics
    )
)
DELETE FROM topics WHERE id = ANY (                      -- 4
    SELECT * FROM trace_tree
);
```

1. This is the recursion (`WITH RECURSIVE`). A recursive CTE contains two parts, combined by the `UNION` clause. First is the recursion initialization. Second is the recursion which joins the previous run on the current table. Finally this returns a list of ids which represents the ancestors of the topic given in the initialization.
2. Next CTE: Delete all entry in the posts_topics join table with all records which contains a topic `t_id` from the list queried above. The `DELETE` statement returns the post ids (`p_id`) which were deleted in this step using `RETURNING`.
3. The previously returned (and deleted) posts' `p_id`s are used in this `DELETE` statement for deleting the real posts.
4. Finally delete all the topics queried in (1)